# ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: css, angularjs, jsp

I got this error while trying to add CSS to my jsp file. Please help me with the solution, I have wasted too much time with it.

GET http://localhost:8080/quan-tri/quan-tri/assets/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: This happens if the file does not exist, could you also share the absolute path of the style.css file in your system?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.